# Change Zip Code required input based on selection

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

i need to change the zip code for a particular country from drop down in vb.net or using javascript  I want to change the zip code requirements as Canada and US do it differently. Canada uses the format of A1A 1A1 for example if i select canada from country the zip code format it should take is A1A 1A1 and for other country it have combination of zipCodePattern = /^\d{5}[A-Z]{1}$|^\d{5}-\d{4}$/; how can i do this.

i have written this

function validateZipCode(zipcode)
     {
         var country = document.getElementById("lblCountry");

```
     if (country=="Canada")
      {

         var zipCodePattern = /^[A-Z}{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}[ ]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$/;
         return zipCodePattern.test(zipcode);
     }
     else 
     {
         var zipCodePattern = /^\w{6}$|^\d{5}-\d{4}$|^\d{5}$/;
         return zipCodePattern.test(zipcode);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript you could make use of the `ternary operator` to switch between patterns (jQuery is used, only because it's simpler to read)

```js
var pattern = '',
    usPattern = '^\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?$',
    caPattern = '^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\\d{1}$'

// watch for country change
$('select').on('change', function(){
  
  // get the selected country
  var val = $(this).val();
  
  // set pattern based on `val` above
  pattern = val == 'us' ? usPattern : caPattern;
  
  // apply pattern to input
  $('input#postcode').attr('pattern', pattern)
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select>
    <option value="us" selected>US</option>
    <option value="ca">CA</option>
  </select>

  <input id="postcode" type="text" pattern="^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```